# Disable Android list view 'blue' background

Tags: android, android-listview

When I click on the list item in Android, I always get a blue background. Event if I use a custom layout, when I click, maybe 2-5dp space around my layout is blue. Also, the text views get darker. How can I disable any changes in view when clicking on the list item?

Comment: `When I click on the list item in Android, I always get a blue background`. blue background for what? the listView or the listView item you're clicking?

Comment: the list view item I'm clicking.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your problem(s) specified clearly? From what I understand, I believe you're mentioning three different problems. Can you explain each one clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom theme for your application in `/res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <!-- application theme -->
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">

    <!-- widget styles -->
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListView</item>
  </style>

  <!-- list view -->
  <style name="ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` specify the theme:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
```

Answer (score 5):

I know its kind of late, but one can also use the `setSelector` method of the listview and set it to `android.R.color.transparent`. You can also use `android:listSelector` in the layout file to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the android drawSelectorOnTop attribute to false on your ListView and there will not be any background when you click on an item.

Eg:

```
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Comment: just adding this attribute didn't help

Comment: I even add a selector for states pressed, selected, focused, but this also didn't help...

Comment: And are you sure you don't have some selector on your item layout that you are adding on the list?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
<ListView 
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        />
```

For more details you can visit here

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 0):

I did it Like this:

```
<ListView
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```